# Small-o asymptotic notation and inequality

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

I am working through a paper and I crossed a point where an inequality becomes an equality, and I am not sure why does it happen. The thing is that one of the term is substituted by a small-o notation term, and so I was wondering if the following is true, taking into account that $f$ is positive:

$f\leq o(g)\rightarrow f=o(g)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true without further assumptions.
For instance take $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^2$, say defined on $(0,1)$. You have $h=o(g)$ for $x\rightarrow0,$ $f(x)\leq h(x)$ but $f$ is not $o(g)$ for $x\rightarrow0$. Indeed
$\frac{f}{g}=-\frac{1}{x^2}\rightarrow-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $0$. But if you assume $f$ to be positive then it is true (by the sandwich theorem).

Comment: $f$ is positive indeed, so I cna say it's true right?

Comment: If $f\geq0$, $f\leq h$ and $h=o(g)$ for $x\rightarrow x_0$ then you get $0\leq \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq \frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$ and the last term goes to $0$ for $x$ going to $x_0$. (I assumed $g$ to be positive near $x_0$ but it is not really important). As always in mathematics, if you are persuaded by an argument, then it is true ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot